# AWS Athena JDBC Query timeout

Tags: jdbc, amazon-athena

I use Amazon Athena via JDBC. Recently I got

```
java.sql.SQLException: Query timeout
```

for several queries, but when I run

```
println(statement.getQueryTimeout)
```

I saw "0" that means that the query timeout is not set up.

How can I solve the problem with timeout exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [AWS Athena Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html):
The athena query timeout is set by default to 30 minutes on server side, 
 you can ask to increse this limitation by AWS Support page

Answer (score -1):

. Split the query into smaller queries to search smaller subsets of data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).